# How do I build BugTrap?

Tags: error-handling, build-process, managed-c++

I am trying to build the [Intellesoft BugTrap](http://www.intellesoft.net/downloads.php) source using Visual Studio 2008.  I have downloaded and unziped the BugTrap source and the zlib source.  I navigated down to ./BugTrap/Win32/BugTrap and opened BugTrap.sln (suggest by the author [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/BugTrap.aspx?msg=2903103#xx2903103xx)).

I used Build->Build Solution and the build failed with a compiler error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zip.h': No such file or directory

I opened the project properties and added the path to the zlib-vc/zlib/include folder to the list of "Additional Include Directories" and tried to build again.

The second build attempt failed with a linker error:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'zlibSD.lib'

I opened the zlib project and built the source.  The zlib build succeeded.  However, the bin directory does not contain a zlibSD.lib.  The closest file in name is zlibMSD.lib. This [poster](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/BugTrap.aspx?msg=2902967#xx2902967xx) on CodeProject seemed to have the same problem I did.  But there is no resolution posted.

Hopefully someone out there has experience building this project and can point me in the right direction, I've played with the binary distribution and it seems really slick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out.  After following the steps listed in the question, perform the following steps to build BugTrap.

1. Add zlib.vcproj to the BugTrap Solution.
2. Open the build Configuration Manager using Build -> Configuration Manager.
3. Change the zlib project configuration from Static MD Debug to Static Debug.  Close.
4. Select the BugTrap project and open the project properties (Project -> Properties).
5. Expand the Configuration Properties -> Linker nodes.
6. Select the General node.  Then add the zlib/bin directory to the list of Additional Library Directories. Click Ok.
7. Build.

Note that the BugTrap project was configured to build in Debug mode, these settings may need to be tweaked for Release mode.   Also, I was not trying to build the BugTrapServer or the CrashExplorer, it seems that there are additional dependencies that will need to be resolved to build those items.

Comment: This works fine if you convert the solution and projects to VS2010 format as well. Thanks for the steps! =)